# jQuery validation softcode the textbox name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                insurance1$ucBuildingInsurance$txtOtherReasonDescription: required
}
});
```

My current script looks like this to validate a textbox txtOtherReasonDescription.Ideally I would like to replace insurance1$ucBuildingInsurance$txtOtherReasonDescription with $() syntax so the control id is not hardcoded. Is there anyway this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the rule using a selector like this:

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
$("input[id$='txtOtherReasonDescription']").rules("add", { required: true });
```

Since you're in ASP.Net, either `id$=` or `name$=` works here, but the concept is set up the valdiation on the form, then attach a rule to the matched elements using [`.rules("add", rulesToAdd)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules).